# ¿Cómo poner una imagen predeterminada de android en un ImageButton desde código?

Tags: java, android

```
ImageButton next;

next.setImageDrawable(?);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exacto, setImageDrawable pondrá la imagen mediante código, pero asegurate de obtener el Drawable por medio de : `next.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nombre_de_tu_imagen));`